# populate and retrieve data in CheckBox list on MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have list of users on my View:

```
foreach (var user in (List<GetWorkDone.Model.Accounts.User>)ViewBag.users)
{
}
```

and user is:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to show list of users in CheckBoxes and get only CheckBoxes selected in ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult AssignUser(List<User> users)
{
}
```

Comment: And your View it's strongly typed to which model?

Comment: It is typed with another model I post users to AssignUser ActionResult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a view model:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public boolean IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public class UsersController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = new UserViewModel[]
        {
            // TODO: obviously those could come from a database or something
            new UserViewModel { UserId = 1, Name = "user 1" },
            new UserViewModel { UserId = 2, Name = "user 2" },
            new UserViewModel { UserId = 3, Name = "user 3" },
        };
        return View(users);
    }

    public ActionResult Index(UserViewModel[] users)
    {
        ... you could inspect the IsSelected property of each user here        
    }
}
```

and finally have a strongly typed view:

```
@model UserViewModel[]
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].UserId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Name)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].IsSelected)
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

And if you already have some other model, then, adapt it and use a view model:

```
public class AssignUserViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel[] Users { get; set; }

    ... some other properties that you already have
}
```

and then:

```
@model AssignUserViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Users.Length; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Users[i].UserId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Users[i].Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Users[i].Name)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Users[i].IsSelected)
        </div>
    }

    ... some other fields

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Conclusion: use a view model - **always**.